# Spring request mapping with regex like in javax.ws.rs

Tags: java, regex, spring, mapping, javax.ws.rs

I'm trying rewrite [this Google App Engine maven server repository](https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository) to Spring.

I have problem with URL mapping.
Maven repo server standard looks like this:

1. URL with slash at the end, points to a folder, example:

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1/testDir/
   http://127.0.0.1/testDir/testDir2/
   ```
2. all others (without slash at the end) point to files, example:

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1/testFile.jar
   http://127.0.0.1/testFile.jar.sha1
   http://127.0.0.1/testDir/testFile2.pom
   http://127.0.0.1/testDir/testFile2.pom.md5
   ```

Original app mapping for [directories](https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository/blob/master/src/main/java/repo/resource/RepositoryResource.java#L90) and for [files](https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository/blob/master/src/main/java/repo/resource/RepositoryResource.java#L125).

There were used annotations `@javax.ws.rs.Path` which supports regexy differently than Spring.

I tried bunch of combinations, for example something like this:

```java
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/{file: .*}")
public String test1(@PathVariable String file) {
    return "test1 " + file;
}

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("{dir: .*[/]{1}$}")
public String test2(@PathVariable String dir) {
    return "test2 " + dir;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in right way in Spring application.

I'd like to avoid writing a custom servlet dispatcher.

Comment: You're not escaping `/` char in your both pattern. It maybe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once, also regarding a Spring implementation of a maven endpoint.

For the file endpoints, you could do something like this

```java
/**
 * An example Maven endpoint for Jar files
 */
@GetMapping("/**/{artifactId}/{version}/{artifactId}-{version}.jar")
public ResponseEntity<String> getJar(@PathVariable("artifactId") String artifactId, @PathVariable("version") String version) {
   ...
}
```

This gives you the `artifactId` and the `version`, but for the `groupId` you would need to do some string parsing. You can get the current `requestUri` with the help of the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`

```java
String requestUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().build().toUri().toString();
// requestUri = /api/v1/com/my/groupId/an/artifact/v1/an-artifact-v1.jar
```

For the folder endpoints, I'm not sure if this will work, but you can give it a try

```java
@GetMapping("/**/{artifactId}/{version}")
public ResponseEntity<String> getJar(@PathVariable("artifactId") String artifactId, @PathVariable("version") String version) {
   // groupId extracted as before from the requestUri
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know  about your java code, but if you are verifying one path at a time, you can just check if the string ends in "/" for a folder and the ones that don't are files

```
\/{1}$
```

this regular expression just checks that the string ends with "/" if there is a match, you have a folder, if there is not, you have a file

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no other specific standard in Spring then the way you have used it. However if you can customize URL then I have a special way to differentiate directory and files. That will increase the scalibility and readability of application and will reduce lot of code for you.

Your Code as of now

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/{file: .*}")
public String test1(@PathVariable String file) {
    return "test1 " + file;
}

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("{dir: .*[/]{1}$}")
public String test2(@PathVariable String dir) {
    return "test2 " + dir;
}
```

Change above code to as below in your controller class

```
private final Map<String, String> managedEntities=ImmutableMap.of(
        "file","Type_Of_Operation_You_want_For_File",
        "directory","Type_Of_Operation_You_want_For_Directory"
        );

@GetMapping(path = "/{type:file|directory}")
public String myFileOperationControl(@PathVariable String type){
        return "Test"+managedEntities.get(type));
        }
```

And proceed further the way you want to per your business logic. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Note:** Please simply enhance endpoint per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't allow matching to span multiple path segments. Path segments are delimited values of path on path separator (/).  So no regex combination will get you there. Spring 5 although allows the span multiple path segments only at the end of path using ** or {*foobar} to capture in foobar uri template variable for reactive stack but I don't think that will be useful for you.

Your options are limited. I think the best option if possible is to use different delimiter than / and you can use regex.

Other option ( which is messy ) to have catch all (**) endpoint and read the path from the request and determine if it is file or directory path and perform actions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```java
@GetMapping("**/{file:.+?\\..+}")
public String processFile(@PathVariable String file, HttpServletRequest request) {   
    return "test1 " + file;
}

@GetMapping("**/{dirName:\\w+}")
public String processDirectory(@PathVariable String dirName, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String dirPath = request.getRequestURI();
    return "test2 " + dirPath;
}
```

Results for URIs from the question:

```
test2 /testDir/
test2 /testDir/testDir2/

test1 testFile.jar
test1 testFile.jar.sha1
test1 testFile2.pom
test1 testFile2.pom.md5
```